# Copy data from PC secretly to USB /Portable Hard disk?

Tags: usb, file-transfer

Can you name any free ware by using which you can copy specific data automatically when you plug in the USB or Portable Hard Drive secretly without alerting the Anti Virus or Malware?

I know one such program that copies data from USB to PC when an USB is plugged in but I want vice versa and it must be a working solution.

Comment: Essentially, you're asking for malware that your malware detector won't detect. I doubt anyone here will feel comfortable giving an answer to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much any program that provides you the ability to setup a sync operation would work.  I am a fan of Robocopy.  Of course the fact you are worried about alterting Malware concerns me, wouldn't it be easier to remove the malicious files, before you continue to use the computer?

If you are trying to get around corporate policy I strongly suggest you do not do so.

Comment: Tools like RoboCopy would work in setting up and automated USB to HDD transfer, but wouldn't work around the AV.

Comment: No it not that I am just working on a project so it requires me to demonstrate that USB's cannot be trusted you can copy data anonymously!

Answer (score 1):

Without first disabling the AV software you won't be able to copy the files without alerting the AV software. The AV software hooks into the native Windows API calls to determine which files are being accessed without having to modify programs to alert it first.

Comment: Well lets suppose the AV is not alerted so then what are my options?

Comment: Well yea I know there are but the point here is to jump to a trusted program, a freeware!

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment @aibk01. If the AV isn't alerted then you've solved your problem (meaning the AV doesn't have real-time scanning or its engine is buggy).

Comment: Well what I mean is that what would be software required to do my job?

Comment: Yes I am asking about the software

Comment: @aibk01 as I mentioned in my answer. Since AV software intercepts raw API calls it would be severely difficult to bypass the AV software. You would have to nuke the AV process before you could copy a virus payload.